# Signature view in gmail sent from outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, footer, signature

I'm trying to set signature in Outlook using HTML. It looks good when I open it on any mail client except for Gmail. Gmail adds additional spaces between lines

```
        <td style="width: 72pt; height:30pt; padding-right: 4pt; color: #696e77; font-family: 'Aeonik Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 7.5pt; line-height: 1.16; letter-spacing: 0.2pt; vertical-align: top; horiz-align: left;">
            <p style="margin: 0.05pt; font-family: 'Aeonik Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 7.5pt; color: #696e77;">
                Company&nbsp;Name
                <br>
                ul.&nbsp;Address&nbsp;123
                <br>
                12-123&nbsp;City
                <br>
                Country
            </p>
        </td>
```

I'd like it to look like this:
Company name
Address
Address2
Country

what I get in gmail instead is:
Company name

Address

Address2

`Country

I tried setting maring to be 0.05px and 0.05pt in the

tag, I also tried wrapping each line separately in

tag with set margin according to this document
https://blog.gimm.io/email-signature-troubleshooting/#1668477177700-51a8a2c9-23ee
, I tried without 
 tag and many more combinations.

Also tried adding

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--
        p.MsoNormal {
            margin: 0px !important;
        }
    -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding bunch of tables, rows and cells inside the main table. Basically I injected each cell with it's own table